# pip doesn't install chatterbot libary

Tags: python, python-3.x, chatterbot

When I try installing chatterbot, I get this error

Here is the link to the error:
https://gist.github.com/SusgUY446/c2c2ae5a1c07aacb0191c35e34d0d0aa

Comment: Your question clearly demonstrates **why** there is a minimum character limit. Your question contains **zero** information other than that you get an error. When asking a question on Stack Overflow about an error, you need to explain what you're trying to do and provide a [mre] (which includes minimum code or commands to reproduce this, and the actual error **as text**) **in the question itself**. If you had done so, you would not have run into the minimum character requirement (and other requirements), and likely it hadn't been closed for lacking details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately chatterbot only supports Python 3.8 and lower.

https://pypi.org/project/ChatterBot/

[image]

You need to downgrade your Python to 3.8 to use Chatterbot.

Comment: and how do i do that without removing 3.12?

Comment: install `3.8` separately.

Answer (score 0):

The diagnostic was pretty clear.

The installer script needs to run the `clang` C compiler,
but you didn't install a compiler and make it available to that script.

```
        running build_ext
        ...
        clang -c C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-rjabvilf\blis_4e316ba9fadc41da8c13b6e248bd31b9\blis\_src\config\bulldozer\bli_cntx_init_bulldozer.c -o ...
        error: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
        [end of output]
```

Either install a pre-built binary package,
or install the build tools prerequisites.
The chatterbot author doesn't seem to have put
much effort into binary distributions,
given that it doesn't appear in the conda-forge feedstock.

Comment: so i now installed clang from llvm.org but its still not working.